# How do I install a gtk theme?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, installation, themes, gtk

You'd think this would be a bit more obvious, but I've been been googling for 45 minutes without anything clear about how to do this.

I've tried installing gnome-art .. but it doesn't have any way to install a theme I downloaded from the internet.  The appearance applet doesn't let me install the theme either.

(the theme is murreza for the murrine engine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head over to Appearance preferences from `Administration->Preferences->Appearance` Menu.
Now, drag and drop `.tgz\.tar.gz` file. Else, click on the `Install` button in Appearance Preferences and navigate to the location where the theme is installed.